# BayesTree package plot extraction in R

Tags: r, plot, bayesian, par

I am using the BayesTree package in R. Using the author's example:

```
##simulate data (example from Friedman MARS paper)
f = function(x){
10*sin(pi*x[,1]*x[,2]) + 20*(x[,3]-.5)^2+10*x[,4]+5*x[,5]
}
sigma = 1.0 #y = f(x) + sigma*z , z~N(0,1)
n = 100 #number of observations
set.seed(99)
x=matrix(runif(n*10),n,10) #10 variables, only first 5 matter
Ey = f(x)
y=Ey+sigma*rnorm(n)

##run BART
set.seed(99)
bartFit = bart(x,y)
plot(bartFit) # plot bart fit
```

When the plot(bartFit) is executed it produces two plots "The plot method sets mfrow to c(1,2) and makes two plots." I am looking to only use the second plot produced from this command. Is there an easy way to extract only the second plot?

This is provided as well:

```
## S3 method for class 'bart':
plot((
   x,
   plquants=c(.05,.95), cols =c('blue','black'),
   ...))
```

I am relatively new to R, in general if a command gives more then 1 plot how can you choose a specific plot you would like? For example in the linear model (lm) plot command you also get multiple plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't have a solution, but maybe I'm onto something. First, I tried to figure which list elements from `bartFit` are plotted on the second plot. You can look at the structure of the bart using `str(bartFit)`. It seems that second plot is created from `$y` and `$yhat.train.mean`, which seems right when you look at it:

```
plot(bartFit$yhat.train.mean ~ bartFit$y)
```

but it's obviously missing the bars. So I decided to change the strategy and `traceback()` to see how those plots are created. No luck, until I changed the name of x-scale to force an error.

```
plot(bartFit, xlab="something")
```

Which gave me only the first plot, error message, but also ability to `traceback()`. There, I could see that the second plot is created using:

```
4: plot.default(x$y, qm, ylim = range(ql, qu), xlab = "y", ylab = "posterior interval for E(Y|x)", ...)
3: plot(x$y, qm, ylim = range(ql, qu), xlab = "y", ylab = "posterior interval for E(Y|x)", ...)
```

but that's not good. I have no idea what is `qm`, or where `ylim` ranges come from. So I started playing with `par`. There I discovered very, very crude solution to use `par` argument `mfg` to "force" plotting only the second plot. This will still leave empty space for one plot, but won't plot it. But it behaves strangely as well. Tricky one.

```
plot(bartFit)
par(mfg=c(1,2))
plot(bartFit)
```

Comment: The last part actually does the trick for me, thank you! I can still put another plot beside it that way which is what I want.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure there is a tidier way to do it, but I'm glad this solution works for you:)